Index Action not served automatically without explicit route
I have an old ASP.NET MVC application running on .NET 4.8.
The Index action doesn't get executed when https://example.com/MyApp/Admin/ is accessed, but it gets correctly served when https://example.com/MyApp/Admin/Index is accessed.
It tries to display the contents of the Admin directory, but I've disabled directory browsing (<directoryBrowse enabled="false" /> under <system.webServer>) so it displays a 403.14.
Routing seems to still be correctly configured:
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteTable.Routes.Clear(); 
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

The default route is also even defined as the same action:
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}

Why is it still failing with an http 403.14 error?

I suspect the purpose of RouteTable.Routes.Clear() in your Global.asax. Meanwhile, your MyApp/Admin/Index route is from basic controller action or from Area?

@YongShun I added the .Clear() just for a test.  The error was the same without the .Clear(). It's a basic controller action without any Areas.

@Zesty: According to the documentation the error more likely related to administration, not to the code itself. HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when you open an IIS webpage
